# Monkey Patching in Python using super.__init__

Tags: python, monkeypatching, python-class, pyrogram

i wanna monkey patch some other class with my own class.
i tried using `Tomonkeypatch.some_func = some_func`. it works but i want to neat method to do so (i.e classes).

I am trying to Monkey patch [Message Object in pyrogram](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram/blob/master/pyrogram/types/messages_and_media/message.py)

Here is my code:

```
import pyrogram

class Message(pyrogram.types.messages_and_media.Message):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    @property
    def test(self):
       return "test"
```

While i use the code in my handler

```
from pyrogram import filters

@client.on_message(filters.private)
async def sometest(client, message):
    s = message.test
    await message.reply(s)
```

i get :

```
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'test'
```

but, i monkey patched in pyrogram? then why?

Thank you, in advance!

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you were expecting. Your code defines a *new* class, which just happens to derive from ``Message``; it does not patch or replace ``Message``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I see. How do you expect me to use it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to monkey patch the original Message object that pyrogram uses.

```
from pyrogram.types import Message 

@property
def test(self):
       return "test"

Message.test = test
```

If you really wanna update the Message class when changing the subclass (NOT RECOMMENDED!) you can do this:

```
from pyrogram.types import Message 

Message.__init_subclass__ = classmethod(lambda sub: [setattr(Message, k, v) for (k,v) in sub.__dict__.items() if k[:2] != '__'])

class MyMessage(Message):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    @property
    def test(self):
        return "test"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works finner than anything :) 

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make a new file, import pyrogram.types.Message, and make a subclass of it.

```py
from pyrogram.types import Message

class MyMessage(Message):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    @property
    def test(self):
        return "test"
```

Then you can import your own `MyMessage` instead of Pyrograms Message and use it as you would normally.

Answer (score 0):

After all I want to share how I did it for all the folks who wants to know:

```
def monkeypatch(obj):
    def wrapper(sub):
        for (func_name, func_) in sub.__dict__.items():
            if func_name[:2] != "__":
                setattr(obj, func_name, func_)
        return sub
    return wrapper
```

Usage:

```
@monkeypatch(songobj)
class something:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def do_it(self):
        print("just an example")
```

Thanks to [@yoily-l](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7163803/yoily-l)

This basically takes a the functions of a class then adds to the someobj attributes.